# How do you get the manifest of an image in GCP artifact registry using the Go SDK?

Tags: docker, go, google-artifact-registry

I am looking to use this library but it does not offer this option. https://cloud.google.com/go/docs/reference/cloud.google.com/go/artifactregistry/latest/apiv1. It seems the struct `artifactregistrypb.DockerImage` simply does not have the option.

Comment: Can you elaborate your question in detail? which option you are looking for?

Comment: I am looking to use `func (c *Client) GetDockerImage(ctx context.Context, req *artifactregistrypb.GetDockerImageRequest, opts ...gax.CallOption) (*artifactregistrypb.DockerImage, error)
` function provided by the go client. However, the returned value `artifactregistrypb.DockerImage` does not have the manifest of the image. My application needs to validate the image manifest before pulling the image. Is there a way to do it? @Roopa M

Comment: In other words, I am looking for a way to only pull the manifest of an image, then validate the manifest. Depending on the validation result, we pull the actual image after that. It seems this option is not available from the GCP sdk or gcloud cli. This option is available in AWS ecr batch-get-image option where we can review the manifest of an image before actually pulling the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was advised to use: Docker Registry HTTP API V2 directly instead of SDK as it is not supported right now:https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/