How to get the manifest of docker image stored in Google Artifact Registry using golang SDK
I'm trying to use this golang sdk to interacte with  Google Artifact Registry: https://google pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/artifactregistry/apiv1
It seems like a lot of docs and examples are missing.
How do I get the manifest data (or the manifest file download URL) of a given artifactregistrypb docker image?
import (
    artifactregistry "cloud.google.com/go/artifactregistry/apiv1"
    "cloud.google.com/go/artifactregistry/apiv1/artifactregistrypb"
     ...
)


func do(ctx context.Context) {
    client, err := artifactregistry.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    repoPath := fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s/locations/%s/repositories/%s", projectID, location, repo)

    dockerImg := getDockerImage(ctx, client, repoPath)

    // dockerImg is of type *artifactregistrypb.DockerImage

    // get the manifest file corresponding to dockerImg
}


There is a ListFiles method that I can use, but I'm not sure how do I match between the dockerImg and corresponding manifest file.
What I essentially looking for is something similar to AWS GetDownloadUrlForLayer API for ECR.

Does this make sense: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795393/13889413

Ended up using github.com/containers/image/v5/docker directly to get the image blob, instead of using the SDK.
import(
    artifactregistry "cloud.google.com/go/artifactregistry/apiv1"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    dockeref "github.com/containers/image/v5/docker/reference"
    imgtypes "github.com/containers/image/v5/types"
    "github.com/containers/image/v5/docker"
)


func do(ctx context.Context) ([]byte, error) {
    namedRef, err := dockeref.ParseDockerRef("us-west1-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/image-name:latest")
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    ref, err := docker.NewReference(namedRef)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    creds, err := google.FindDefaultCredentials(ctx, artifactregistry.DefaultAuthScopes()...)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    token, err := creds.TokenSource.Token()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    img, err := ref.NewImage(ctx, &imgtypes.SystemContext{
        DockerBearerRegistryToken: token.AccessToken,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return img.ConfigBlob(ctx) 
}

